# press Yes, No, Enter to continue in powershell script

Tags: powershell, shell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a script called `install.ps1` that calls `install.py`.

When I execute `.\install.ps1`, it prompts me `Y/N` if I want to upgrade python. then `install.ps1` calls install.py that prompts few more options like in which dir you want to install python, press `ENTER` if you want to use default path.

I want to automate this process where my automation will automatically press either Y or N followed by Enter 5 times.
I tried this but it still prompts me to press `Y/N`. How should I do it?

```
echo "N`n`n`n`n`n" | .\install.ps1
```

EDIT: This is the part of code that is giving 1st prompt that comes from install.ps1. After this next prompt comes from install.py.

```
    $message  = 'Do you want to upgrade Python?'
    $question = 'press Y? (Entering "n" will use existing python)'

    $choices = New-Object Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]
    $choices.Add((New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription -ArgumentList '&Yes'))
    $choices.Add((New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription -ArgumentList '&No'))

    $decision = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($message, $question, $choices, 0)
```

Comment: [1] are you certain that the PoSh script is asking those questions? i would expect the python installer to ask them. [2] if you want to feed arguments to a PoSh script, try reading `Get-Help about_Functions_Advanced`. [3] if you want to feed keystrokes ... i suggest you look into `AutoIT` or `AutoHotKey`. [4] you likely otta read the install instructions for python ... i suspect that it has a silent install method. [*grin*]

Comment: [1] Please see my edit. 1st prompt comes from powershell, rest comes from python. 
[4] I am writing a test to test install.py. its a local script to install a python based tool. Silent install testing is done. I need a way to automate est manual install part.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. ///// PoSh is ... quite poor at UI stuff. i don't recommend it for that. use something that IS designed for UI stuff ... like AutoIT. it has a powershell module ... [*grin*]

Comment: PowerShell has access to both WinForms and WPF using .Net. GUI is not an issue with PowerShell, the structure of building GUIs in Windows is (until you know how)... Also, to interact with Windows GUI, you can always work with the .Net SendKey() method (the same as AutoIt does behind the scenes).